# Why can't I initialize a static variable with a non literal value?

Tags: c, static, constants

I had this code:

```
int foo(void){
    return 1;
}

int main(void){
    static const int x = foo();

    //do stuff
    return 0;
}
```

But I got an error about initializing a static variable with a non-const value. I thought it had something to do with the const specifier, but it didn't. I ended dropping the const keyword and doing this:

```
int foo(void){
    return 1;
}

int main(void){
    static int x = 0;
    if (x == 0) x = foo();

    //do stuff
    return 0;
}
```

Now, why can't the compiler just delay the initialization of the `static int x` variable until it's used, and more importantly, why can't it just put it in a read-write section, and just enforce that it's not written to in compile time? I'd like to use the `const` AND `static` keyword for improved semantics in my code, but I don't really care how the compiler handles this, just let it work.

Is my understanding of the C standard wrong? Or is my compiler sucking? It's MSVC 9.0.

Comment: What is static variable in main good for?

Comment: 'x' looks like a local variable in the context of your example.  Why do you want this to be static?

Comment: @ValAkkapeddi: Often due to the fact that you don't need/want to reinitialize it for each call to that function.

Comment: Sorry, it's not in main actually, I just put it in main so the snippet could be compiled standalone.

Comment: @tchap: It's useful if the object is too large to fit on the stack, or if you want to re-enter `main`. (In C it's legal to call `main` recursively.)

Comment: @Spidey - The answers quoting the standard are correct.  Another way to look at it is that the static variables are initialized by the compiler, prior to runtime.  In gcc, they are usually contiguous in an .sdata section loaded from disk into memory.

Comment: In MSVC 2015, the first snippet now compiles :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C requires it.

From the C Standard:

> (C99, 6.7.8p4) "All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals."

Note that the `const` qualifier does not mean constant but rather read-only. A `const` object is not a constant in C.

The reason a static object cannot be initialized by a non constant value is related to the fact that the initialization of a static object is done *"prior to program startup"* (C99, 6.2.4p3).

Comment: Please, explain what's the difference between a const object and a constant in C. A constant in C is a literal value?

Comment: The definition of a constant expression in C is extremely limited. It's defined in C99 in 6.6 Constant Expressions (html version at http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.6)

Comment: @Spidey a constant is basically a scalar literal, see C99, 6.4.4 for the definition. A constant is a constant expression. A `const` object is neither a constant nor a constant expression.

Comment: then how come you are allowed to do so in C++?

Comment: @SahandMozaffari C and C++ are two different languages (even if C inspired C++ and then C++ inspired C). Note that in C++, contrary to C, a `const` is really a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The value for initialization must be determined at compile or link time. C doesn't have the concept of constructors that could be run at the startup of the program.

Answer (score 1):

This constraint comes from C standard's section 6.7.8/4, so it's not just your compiler:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

The reason for this is that unlike C++ standard, C sdoes not require execution environments to provide an entry point for pre-run initialization (while certainly not *prohibiting* it; The manner and timing of static initialization (5.1.2) is *unspecified*).